# "undefined method `stub_request'" when accessing the method in an RSpec support file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following file struture in my Ruby-on-Rails project, for the specs:

```
/spec
  /msd
    /service
      service_spec.rb
  /support
    /my_module
      requests_stubs.rb
```

My `request_stubs.rb` have:

```
module MyModule::RequestsStubs

  module_function

  def list_clients
    url = "dummysite.com/clients"
    stub_request(:get, url).to_return(status: 200, body: "clients body")
  end
end
```

In my `service_spec.rb` I have:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/my_module/requests_stubs'
...
```

because I only want the method available in this file.

The problem is that when running the tests I call the method `MyModule::RequestsStubs.list_clients` in the `service_spec.rb` file, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error:
       stub_request(:get, url).to_return(status: 200, body: "clients body")

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub_request' for MyModule::RequestsStubs:Module
```

when accessing the WebMock method `stub_request`.

The WebMock gem is installed and is required in the `spec_helper.rb` file.

Why does the error occurs? It looks like it can't access the WebMock gem, or don't know how to access it. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`stub_request` is defined in the `WebMock` namespace, so you have to use `WebMock.stub_request`. To make it available globally, you need to add `include WebMock::API` to your rails_helper.

Even better, include `webmock/rspec` instead of just `webmock` -- it will take care of including the `WebMock::API` as well as setting up the webmock RSpec matchers.

Comment: Did you mean ”require `webmock/rspec`”?

Comment: In my case `spec_helper` was requiring `webmock/rspec` but `rails_helper` was not requiring `spec_helper`